# how to display the sum of all the attachment size using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a form that upload a file. and script to show attachment in  a list..

i want to display the sum of all attachment size in a text input...
but it display only the last data..

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="files"  multiple/>
<input type="text" value="" id="all_size">
<div id="selectedFiles"></div>
</form>
```

and here is the script:

```
var selDiv = "";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

function init() {
    document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    selDiv = document.querySelector("#selectedFiles");
}

function handleFileSelect(e) {

    if(!e.target.files) return;

    selDiv.innerHTML = "";


    var files = e.target.files;
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        var f = files[i];

        selDiv.innerHTML += "<span class='attach'>" + f.name + " <" + f.size + " bytes>" + "</span>";

        document.getElementById("all_size").value = f.size; 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function handleFileSelect(e) {

    if(!e.target.files) return;

    selDiv.innerHTML = "";

    var sum = 0;
    var files = e.target.files;
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        sum += f.size;
        var f = files[i];

        selDiv.innerHTML += "<span class='attach'>" + f.name + " <" + f.size + " bytes>" + "</span>";
    }

    document.getElementById("all_size").value = sum; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var selDiv = "";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

function init() {
    document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    selDiv = document.querySelector("#selectedFiles");
}

function handleFileSelect(e) {

    if(!e.target.files) return;

    selDiv.innerHTML = "";


    var files = e.target.files;
    var total_size = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        var f = files[i];
        total_size += f.size;
        selDiv.innerHTML += "<span class='attach'>" + f.name + " <" + f.size + " bytes>" + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("all_size").value = total_size; 

    }

}
```